# Why are the Trie Functions unable to produce my desired output?

Tags: java, data-structures, tree, trie

Your task is to create a trie system that is hosted online with a global state that supports multiple concurrent clients and the following operations:

1. Add keyword to trie
2. Delete a keyword from trie
3. Search for a keyword in trie [True/False]
4. Return list of autocomplete suggestion based on an input prefix
5. Display the trie

Node Class:

```
package com.stack.trie;

public class Node {
    public Node[] links = new Node[26];
    public int ctrEndWith;
    public int ctrPrefix;
    public boolean flag;

        boolean containsKey(char ch)
        {
            return (links[ch-'a']!=null);
        }

        Node get(char ch)
        {
            return links[ch-'a'];
        }

        void put(char ch,Node node)
        {
            links[ch-'a']=node;
        }

        void increaseEnd()
        {
            ctrEndWith++;
        }

        void increasePrefix()
        {
            ctrPrefix++;
        }

        void deleteEnd()
        {
            ctrEndWith--;
        }

        void reducePrefix()
        {
            ctrPrefix--;
        }

        int getEnd()
        {
            return ctrEndWith;
        }

        int getPrefix()
        {
            return ctrPrefix;
        }

        void setEnd()
        {
            flag=true;
        }

        boolean isEnd()
        {
            return flag;
        }
}
```

And Functions:

```
public class Trie1 {
    public Node root = new Node();

    public void add(String word) {
        Node node = root;
        int i;
        for (i = 0; i < word.length(); i++) {
            if (node.containsKey(word.charAt(i))) {
                node.put(word.charAt(i), new Node());
            }
            node = node.get(word.charAt(i));
            node.increasePrefix();
        }
        node.setEnd();
    }

    public boolean search(String word) {
        Node node = root;
        int i;
        for (i = 0; i < word.length(); i++) {
            if (!node.containsKey(word.charAt(i))) {
                return false;
            }
            node = node.get(word.charAt(i));
        }
        return node.isEnd();
    }

    void delete(String word) {
        Node node = root;
        int i;
        for (i = 0; i < word.length(); i++) {
            if (node.containsKey(word.charAt(i))) {
                node = node.get(word.charAt(i));
                node.reducePrefix();
            } else {
                return;
            }
        }
        node.deleteEnd();
    }

    void suggest() {

    }

    String display() {
        return null;
    }

    public void mainMenu() {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        int ch;
        String str;
        do {
            System.out.println("\t\tTrie Menu");
            System.out.println("\t\t1.Add");
            System.out.println("\t\t2.Delete");
            System.out.println("\t\t3.Search");
            System.out.println("\t\t4.Return Suggestions");
            System.out.println("\t\t5.Display Trie");
            System.out.println("\t\t6.Exit");
            System.out.print("\t\tPlease enter a choice.");
            ch = sc.nextInt();

            switch (ch) {
                case 1:
                    System.out.println("Enter keyword to be added");
                    str = sc.nextLine();
                    add(str);
                    break;
                case 2:
                    System.out.println("Enter keyword to be deleted");
                    str = sc.nextLine();
                    break;
                case 3:
                    System.out.println("Please enter search term");
                    str = sc.nextLine();
                    search(str);
                    break;
                case 4:
                    System.out.println("Please enter prefix");
                    str = sc.nextLine();
                    break;
                case 5:
                    display();
                    break;
                case 6:
                    System.out.println("Thank you!");
                    break;
                default:
                    System.out.println("Invalid Input. Please try again.");
            }
        } while (ch != 6);
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        Trie1 obj = new Trie1();
        obj.mainMenu();
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you have an example? What do you input? What is the output? What should be the output?

Answer (score 0):

On a first scan over your code already I identified two problems.

First problem:

In `mainMenu()` you use `sc.nextInt()` to read the menu selection. After that you use `sc.nextLine()` (for example to read the keyword to be added). This is problematic because `sc.nextInt()` did not consume the line terminator after the int and therefore you always get an empty string for the keyword.

See [Scanner is skipping nextLine() after using next() or nextFoo()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13102045/scanner-is-skipping-nextline-after-using-next-or-nextfoo) for more information.

In `mainMenu()` replace

```
ch = sc.nextInt();
```

with

```
ch = sc.nextInt();
sc.nextLine();
```

---

Second problem:

In the `Trie1.add()` method you add a new `Node` object to the current node only if it already contains a node:

```
        if (node.containsKey(word.charAt(i))) {
            node.put(word.charAt(i), new Node());
        }
```

You need to reverse the condition in the if statement:

```
        if (!node.containsKey(word.charAt(i))) {
            node.put(word.charAt(i), new Node());
        }
```

---

Also, why does your main method contain the line

```
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
```

You never use that `sc` so delete that unnecessary line.